# Objective C - basis class of UIButton and UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, inheritance

I am currently creating my own table model. My problem is that i wanna be able to put UILabel as well as UIButtons in the fields. To do so i have to make the field * to something both of them inert from.

my question: is there a basis class that UILabel and UIButton share together? Something like UIElement would be great.

Comment: If you read the "Inherits from" line right at the top of the UILabel and UIButton class references, you will quickly find it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the future i will do that before posting similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of them inherits from UIView

Answer (score 1):

The first common subclass of UILabel and UIButton is UIView.